# PHP, CODEIGNITER :cannot use DOMPDF on windows with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdf

I am using dompdf libary to generate a pdf page from html. and I use ubuntu 14.05(manualy install mysql and apache) as my dev machine. my program success to generate a pdf

**BUT**

when i run my project on windows 7 32bit and 10 64bit (both fresh install, using xampp) instead generate pdf, it display nothing and return error in the firebug's console log, this is the error:

```html
 Error: Invalid XRef stream
pdf.worker.js (line 243)
<System>

XRef_readXRef@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3727:15
XRef_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3325:23
PDFDocument_setup@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2493:7
PDFDocument_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2374:7
ensureHelper@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1992:22
NetworkPdfManager_ensure/<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2006:7
NetworkPdfManager_ensure@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1986:1
BasePdfManager_ensureDoc@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1853:14
loadDocument/</<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:33409:11

pdf.worker.js (line 244)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
pdf.worker.js (line 235)
<System>
```

this is custom library **pdf.php** file located in application/libraries

```html
<?php
 class CI_Pdf {
  function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation,$view=TRUE, $stream=TRUE)
  {
   require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
   spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
   $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
   $dompdf->set_paper($paper,$orientation);
   $dompdf->load_html($html);
   $dompdf->render();
   if ($stream) {
    if ($view) {
     $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));//display on browser 
    }else{
     $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>1));//download pdf
    }    
   } else {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper("file");
    write_file($filename, $dompdf->output());
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

this is my controller **cetak.php** located in application/controllers

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cetak extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('pdf');
 }
 public function index()
 {
  
  $title_page = 'Daftar Mahasiswa';
  $data = array(
     array('nama' => 'Kuda1','alamat' => 'Kota Bogor','asal' => 'Bogor juga'),
     array('nama' => 'Kuda2','alamat' => 'Kota Bogor','asal' => 'Bogor juga'),
     array('nama' => 'Kuda3','alamat' => 'Kota Bogor','asal' => 'Bogor juga'),
     array('nama' => 'Kuda4','alamat' => 'Kota Bogor','asal' => 'Bogor juga'),
     array('nama' => 'Kuda5','alamat' => 'Kota Bogor','asal' => 'Bogor juga'),
   );
  //misalkan load data data dari database ,tinggal panggil model / load langsung di controller.
  
  //load html dari viev ^_^
  $HTML=$this->load->view('v_print',array('title_page'=>$title_page,'data_mahasiswa'=>$data),true);
  $this->pdf->pdf_create($HTML,$title_page,'A4','potrait');//render atau membuat pdf dari html diatas
  //$this->pdf->pdf_create($HTML,$title_page,'A4','potrait',FALSE);//jika langsung didownload pdf-nya
 }
  
}

/* End of file print.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/print.php */
```

file **v_print.php** located in application/views

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 tr>th{
  background-color: gray;
 }
 tr>th,tr>td{
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
<h2><?php echo $title_page ?></h2>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>No.</th>
  <th>Nama</th>
  <th>Alamat</th>
  <th>Asal</th>
 </tr>
 <?php 
 $no=1;
 foreach ($data_mahasiswa as $key){
  echo '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$no.'</td>
    <td>'.$key['nama'].'</td>
    <td>'.$key['alamat'].'</td>
    <td>'.$key['asal'].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
  $no++;
 }
 ?> 
</table>
```

if my question is not clear pelase ask. Thanks^^

Comment: if your are using codeigniter 3, check for file names of controllers, models and libraries.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju , my program run well on ubuntu machine. doesnt it mean I have fine file names?. if you want i will add link to my sample program

Comment: @stacheldraht27 chnage this to `if ($stream) {
    if ($view) {` this `if ($stream==TRUE) {
    if ($view=TRUE) {`

Comment: @Abdulla what does that mean

Comment: @Abdulla still doesnt work